# Postgres - is it possible set search_path to multiple schema?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

Is it possible to set search_path to multiple schema?

Below is my test on postgres: set search_path to multiple schema.

```
db=# begin; set search_path to SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2; 
db=# SHOW search_path;
```

Show search_path return SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2, but when search data, display data from one schema : SCHEMA1. Unable to find data on SCHEMA2

Thank You

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Can you show a complete SQL script that exhibits the problem?

Comment: If you mean "SELECT * FROM table1" should automatically return results from "schema1.table1" AND "schema2.table1" together then no. They are two different tables and the fact that they have the same name is a meaningless coincidence.

Comment: $db = Yii::$app->db;        
$command = $db->createCommand('SET search_path TO ' . implode(',', $schemas) . ';');
  $command->execute();

Answer (score 1):

given the small amount of description for the question I am not sure if this is what they might be asking. however, my take on it is this might be helpful.

```
create schema if not exists test ;
create schema if not exists general ;

drop table if exists test.x;
create table test.x(
    id integer generated always as identity primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    unique (name)
);

drop table if exists test.y;
create table test.y(
    id integer generated always as identity primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    unique (name)
);

drop table if exists general.y;
create table general.y(
    id integer generated always as identity primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    unique (name)
);

drop table if exists general.w;
create table general.w(
    id integer generated always as identity primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    unique (name)
);

drop table if exists public.z;
create table public.z(
    id integer generated always as identity primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    unique (name)
);


insert into test.x (name) values('i am data from test.x');
insert into test.y (name) values('i am data from test.y');
insert into general.y (name) values('i am data from general.y');
insert into general.w (name) values('i am data from general.w');
insert into public.z (name) values('i am data from public.z');


SET search_path TO test,general;


select * from x;

id |         name
----+-----------------------
1 | i am data from test.x
(1 row)

select * from y;

id |         name
----+-----------------------
1 | i am data from test.y
(1 row)

-- given the path that we are using test,general
-- test's y blocks getting data from general's y so we need to state schema as 
-- part of the table name to get it's data.
select * from general.y;

id |           name
----+--------------------------
1 | i am data from general.y
(1 row)

-- general's w however does not need the schema name prepended to the table name
select * from w;

id |           name
----+--------------------------
1 | i am data from general.w
(1 row)


-- likewise z only exists in public, so you could just use z. but... 
-- its not on the search path so it will not be found.
select * from z;

ERROR:  relation "z" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from z;
                    ^

-- thus we would need to state the schema name to select from it.
select * from public.z;

id |          name
----+-------------------------
1 | i am data from public.z
(1 row)

-- lastly, if we wanted both the data from test.y and general.y we could use union
-- for clarity i am giving the schema name for both y's

select * from test.y
union
select * from general.y;

id |           name
----+--------------------------
1 | i am data from test.y
1 | i am data from general.y
(2 rows)
```